# Design question

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I need to download a file from web. Which way is preferred

1. WebRequest/WebResponse
2. WebClient

Rick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WebClient` is simpler and provides a [`DownloadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx) method that should do what you want.

If you find you need more control over the process, you could switch to using `WebRequest`. `WebClient` is a wrapper around `WebRequest`/`WebResponse`.

Answer (score 1):

`WebClient` will be easier to work with, though will offer less control.