# Sending HTTP requests with C# HttpWebRequest or WebClient?

Tags: c#, http

I can use both  `HttpWebRequest` to send an HTTP request and get an HTTP response without a `WebClient`.

When should you use `HttpWebRequest` and when should you use `WebClient`?

Comment: Almost the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123543/design-question

Answer (score 3):

WebClient can be used when you don't need any fine-tuning.

When using HttpWebRequest, you can control various options, including timeouts (very important). So basically - WebClient for toy projects / POCs, HttpWebRequest for actual business.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I always use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx). The API seems more simple. It uses HttpWebRequest under the covers.

Answer (score 0):

WebClient is ideal for downloads and uploads.

HttpWebRequest is ideal for web connections, including sending HTTP POST requests, as seen here: [HTTP request with post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post/4015346#4015346)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need access to the underlying stream but are just uploading or downloading "data", i.e. a file some bytes or a string, WebClient is a simplifying abstraction.